How can I hide ordered list index numbers in Safari?
I want to know how can I remove a style that's applied only on Safari browser, by Safari itself. On Google Chrome and Mozilla, the numbers below these carousel indicators are hidden by me. I was initially using Bootstrap 5.0, and these numbers were not present, but when changing to Bootstrap 5.3.2 they appeared, so I used this to hide them:
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-bs-target=".carousel-reviews[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/nJgyZ.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/nJgyZ.png)" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-bs-target=".carousel-reviews" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>

.carousel-reviews li::marker
{
    content: none;
}

It worked pretty well, but now that I checked on Safari (both iPhone and Macbook), they are still there.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Have you tried .carousel-reviews li::marker { content: none !important; }?

Yes, it had no effect.

Caniuse says ::marker styling is limited to font-size and color on Safari up to and including v17.4. Could you use list-style on the li element itself instead?

@Alohci - Thank you for reminding me about CanIUse. This is a site that should always be checked when one sees differing behaviors between browsers for "standard" HTML and CSS.

Why are you deviating from standard practice and putting your indicators in a list?
